# Parsing and manipulating log file with embedded xml

Tags: xml, bash, perl, sed

I have a log file that has embedded xml amongst normal STDOUT in it as follows:

```
2015-05-06 04:07:37.386 [INFO]Process:102 - Application submitted Successfully ==== 1
<APPLICATION><FirstName>Test</FirstName><StudentSSN>123456789</StudentSSN><Address>123 Test Street</Address><ParentSSN>123456780</ParentSSN><APPLICATIONID>2</APPLICATIONID></APPLICATION>
2015-05-06 04:07:39.386 [INFO] Process:103 - Application completed Successfully ==== 1
2015-05-06 04:07:37.386 [INFO]Process:104 - Application submitted Successfully ==== 1
<APPLICATION><FirstName>Test2</FirstName><StudentSSN>323456789</StudentSSN><Address>234 Test Street</Address><ParentSSN>123456780</ParentSSN><APPLICATIONID>2</APPLICATIONID></APPLICATION>
2015-05-06 04:07:39.386 [INFO] Process:105 - Application completed Successfully ==== 1
```

My objective is to parse this file and replace any occurences of personal data with ***. Therefore, the desired output after the script above should be:

```
2015-05-06 04:07:37.386 [INFO]Process:102 - Application submitted Successfully ==== 1
<APPLICATION><FirstName>***</FirstName><StudentSSN>***</StudentSSN><Address>*******</Address><ParentSSN>*********</ParentSSN>   <APPLICATIONID>2</APPLICATIONID></APPLICATION>
2015-05-06 04:07:39.386 [INFO] Process:103 - Application completed Successfully ==== 1
2015-05-06 04:07:37.386 [INFO]Process:104 - Application submitted Successfully ==== 1
<APPLICATION><FirstName>***</FirstName><StudentSSN>*********</StudentSSN><Address>*****</Address><ParentSSN>*********</ParentSSN>   <APPLICATIONID>2</APPLICATIONID></APPLICATION>
2015-05-06 04:07:39.386 [INFO] Process:105 - Application completed Successfully ==== 1
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: the issues in the xml are typos from you, or from the application generating the log?

Comment: @Guido any issues in the tags (such as a space) is a typo. But the xml is generated in the log file just as I have above the starting tag of the line is "Application" and closes with that. Does that makes sense?

Comment: honestly, no; you have the `FirstName` element not correctly closed, and same for the `applicationid` element: it is generated like that, ie. it's invalid xml, or it is just in the snippet you posted (and the xml in the logfile is to be considered valid xml)?

Comment: ok, so why don't you filter the logfile with something (grep or anything else) for just the xml lines, and pipe it to your already made perl script?

Comment: @guido, Here is my sample perl script http://pastie.org/10187948

Comment: My issue is how do I get the lines that are not to be edited too, to be in the new file?

Comment: @FatOwl: Please revert your last edit (deleted 1628 characters in body). Your question is now not helpful to others.

Comment: Have rolled back edit, so question remains relevant.

Answer (score 2):

Create file foo.sed with this content:

```
s|<FirstName>[^<]*</FirstName>|<FirstName>***</FirstName>|
s|<StudentSSN>[^<]*</StudentSSN>|<StudentSSN>***</StudentSSN>|
s|<Address>[^<]*</Address>|<Address>***</Address>|
s|<ParentSSN>[^<]*</ParentSSN>|<ParentSSN>***</ParentSSN>|
```

And try this with GNU sed:

```
sed -f foo.sed log_file > new_file
```

Or edit file "in place":

```
sed -i -f foo.sed log_file
```

Comment: that did the trick. Genius! Thank you so very much. I didnt realize it would be this easy!

Comment: I have added the content back as well as started a new post with my new question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30249841/using-wildcards-with-sed