# Using wildcards with sed

Tags: regex, sed

I have a log file that has embedded xml amongst normal STDOUT in it as follows:

```
2015-05-06 04:07:37.386 [INFO]Process:102 - Application submitted Successfully ==== 1
<APPLICATION><FirstName>Test</FirstName><StudentSSN>123456789</StudentSSN><Address>123 Test Street</Address><ParentSSN>123456780</ParentSSN><APPLICATIONID>2</APPLICATIONID></APPLICATION>
2015-05-06 04:07:39.386 [INFO] Process:103 - Application completed Successfully ==== 1
2015-05-06 04:07:37.386 [INFO]Process:104 - Application submitted Successfully ==== 1
<APPLICATION><FirstName>Test2</FirstName><StudentSSN>323456789</StudentSSN><Address>234 Test Street</Address><ParentSSN>123456780</ParentSSN><APPLICATIONID>2</APPLICATIONID></APPLICATION>
2015-05-06 04:07:39.386 [INFO] Process:105 - Application completed Successfully ==== 1
```

which I am successfully parsing as per a solution provided to me in [Parsing and manipulating log file with embedded xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30229816/parsing-and-manipulating-log-file-with-embedded-xml) . As per the post there, I use a .sed file with commands as follows:

```
s|<FirstName>[^<]*</FirstName>|<FirstName>***</FirstName>|
s|<StudentSSN>[^<]*</StudentSSN>|<StudentSSN>***</StudentSSN>|
s|<Address>[^<]*</Address>|<Address>***</Address>|
s|<ParentSSN>[^<]*</ParentSSN>|<ParentSSN>***</ParentSSN>|
```

My question is, is there a way to do a wild card match in the foo.sed file you have up above? So for example, if I wanted to match all *SSN tags and replace those with a **, rather than have one line for StudentSSN and another for ParentSSN and still yield the output as below:

```
2015-05-06 04:07:37.386 [INFO]Process:102 - Application submitted Successfully ==== 1
<APPLICATION><FirstName>***</FirstName><StudentSSN>***</StudentSSN><Address>*******</Address><ParentSSN>*********</ParentSSN>   <APPLICATIONID>2</APPLICATIONID></APPLICATION>
2015-05-06 04:07:39.386 [INFO] Process:103 - Application completed Successfully ==== 1
2015-05-06 04:07:37.386 [INFO]Process:104 - Application submitted Successfully ==== 1
<APPLICATION><FirstName>***</FirstName><StudentSSN>*********</StudentSSN><Address>*****</Address><ParentSSN>*********</ParentSSN>   <APPLICATIONID>2</APPLICATIONID></APPLICATION>
2015-05-06 04:07:39.386 [INFO] Process:105 - Application completed Successfully ==== 1
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: Most likely possible but unless there is compelling reason to not have multiple lines it's probably better as it is. Using a more clever solution will make it harder to understand even for yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[choroba's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30251079/45375) works well with *GNU* `sed`, because using `\|` for alternation in a *basic* regular expression (implied by the absence of the `-r` option) is only supported there.

Also, the OP has since expressed a desire to use *patterns* to match *similar* element names.

Here's a solution that makes uses of ***extended*** regular expressions, which should work on both Linux (GNU Sed) and BSD/OSX platforms (BSD Sed):

```
sed -E 's%<([^>]*Name|[^>]*SSN|Address[^>]*)>[^<]*%<\1>***%g' file
```

Note:

- It is import to match the variable parts of the element names with `[^>]*` rather than `.*` so as to ensure that the matches remain confined to the opening tag.
- BSD/OSX *extended* regular expressions (in accordance with POSIX extended regular expressions) do not support *backreferences inside the regular expression itself* (as opposed to the "backreferences" that refer to capture-group matches in the *replacement string*), so no attempt is made to match the closing tag with one.
- While this command works on the stated platforms, it is *not* POSIX-compliant, because POSIX only mandates support for *basic* regular expressions in Sed.

The above command is the e**quivalent of the following *GNU* Sed command** using a *basic* regular expression - note the need to escape `(`, `)`, and `|`:

```
sed  's%<\([^>]*Name\|[^>]*SSN\|Address[^>]*\)>[^<]*%<\1>***%g' file
```

Note, that it is the use of alternation (`\|`) that makes this command *not* portable, because *POSIX* basic regular expressions do not support it.

Comment: Yes I am using OSX. I am using this command from within a sed file. And `s%<\([^>]*Name\|[^>]*SSN\|Address[^>]*\)>[^<]*%<\1>***%g` is not working. Could you please advice?

Comment: @mklament01 `s%<([^>]*Name|[^>]*SSN|Address[^>]*)>[^<]*%<\1>***%g` with the -E works perfectly! Thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

You can use an alternative with `\|`. I changed the delimiter to `%` because of that:

```
sed -e 's%<\(FirstName\|StudentSSN\|Address\|ParentSSN\)>[^<]*</\1>%<\1>***</\1>%g'
```

Comment: A variant of choroba's solution: `sed 's%<\(FirstName\|.*SSN\|Address\)>[^<]*</\1>%<\1>***</\1>%g' file`

Comment: @Cyrus pardon my ignorance, but if I had say, an Address1 and Address2 and a OwnerFirst, CoOwenerFirst. I did something like this, and am getting an error around unbalanced paranthesis:
   
    `s|<(.*First\|.*SSN\|Address.*\)>[^<]*</\1>%<\1>***</\1>|`

This is my entry in the .sed file that I run against my log file

Comment: A line like this in the .sed file gives me an error
`s|<.*First\|.*SSN\|Address.*\>[^<]*</\1>%<\1>***</\1>|`
*sed: 1: batchLogMasking.sed: RE error: repetition-operator operand invalid*

Comment: An entry like this does nothing
`s%<\(.*Name\|.*SSN\|Address.*\)>[^<]*</\1>%<\1>***</\1>%g`

The command I am using is 

` sed -f batchLogMasking.sed Batch.txt >> n.out`
Where, the batchLogMasking.sed contains the command above. Please advice as to where I am going wrong.

Comment: @FatOwl: The main problem is the use of `.*` inside the alternation, which is too greedy.

Comment: @mklement0 I see. Is there a way around this?

Comment: @mklement0 I added the following to my sed file
`s%<([^>]*Name|[^>]*SSN|Address[^>]*)>[^<]*%<\1>***%g`
 and i get
`sed: 1: batchLogMasking.sed: \1 not defined in the RE`

Comment: @mklement0 using a BRE like this, within the sed file, replaces nothing :(
`s%<\([^>]*Name\|[^>]*SSN\|Address[^>]*\)>[^<]*%<\1>***%g`

Comment: This sounds like you're using BSD `sed`, on OSX, right? It's an _ERE_, not a BRE, so you need the `-E`  option; please post further comments below _my_ answer.